# New Contributor indicator how to be a Contributor to Code of Conduct?

Tags: support, new-users

While Browsing [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). I noticed that some users are Contributor of "Code of Conduct".

[image]

If You hover the Text 'New Contributor' it Shows a message about "Code of Conduct". Although I already know about this code of conduct but I want to know , ***How to be a Contributor to Code of Conduct***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This flag doesn't mean that the user is a *"Contributor to the Code of Conduct"*. It means that this user is new to the site and thus should be treated in a more welcoming manner in accordance with the Code of Conduct. In fact, you are a new contributor to this site and other users will see this flag on you for some time.

[image: You are a new contributor!]

This flag is visible for a week following the user's first post. In your case, that was your first post in meta, hence the flag. For more information, see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator).

Comment: But some New Users with Reputation less than 50 are not shown with this Flag.

Comment: @ShehrozKhan Sure, that's possibly because they asked a question a long time ago and had minimal contributions since then, that is, they are not new to the site. For more information, see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator).